# i have 1000 pages now i want to display page views on my website,can this be done from google analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If i have 1000 users and every one have 1 page on my website,
now i want to display Page views on my website (respectively on user pages).
Can this be done from google analytics API ?
IF yes then what is full procedure ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow doesn't give out answers without effort and prior research. Show some effort and some relevant code, please.

Comment: who said i did'nt research about Query.?

Comment: if you don't know then please do not comment here.

Comment: Clearly you are not familiar with Stack Overflow. Please take the SO tour and revise your question.

Comment: Here's the link to the SO tour for your convenience: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What you are looking for is [Server side auth](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/). This question gets asked often. It boils down to this: Understand the difference between your data and your users data. The API is setup to allow your users to access **their** data. It is going to require work on your part to allow your users to see **your** data.

Comment: @Matt then how great website like www.forbes.com count page view and display it on website ??

Comment: They probably query the API [Server side](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) and display that information to their users much like they do any other data. They don't require their users to authenticate against their site to access their own analytics data. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168173/is-it-possible-to-integrate-google-analytics-dashboard-to-our-own-website/37173776#37173776) to get a better picture of what I am talking about.