# Is it possible to integrate google analytics dashboard to our own website?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to show google analytics dashboard to my users. It is not possible to give access of "google analytics dashboard" to all users. So I want to integrate it on my own website. Will it be possible to integrate google analytics dashboard on a particular website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question gets asked quite a bit. It is important to understand the security model for the API. All Google APIs use [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authenticate the user. This is designed to make it easy to use the API to access the **Users's data** on behalf of the user. In contrast you will need to do work to show **Your data** to your users.

With that said, an example of what you are looking for is the [Server side Auth example](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) provided by the Analytics API team.

The simplest answer is to query the API on the server side, with a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount) and serve that data as you serve any other data to your users. **Read the scenarios in detail**, and pick one that best suits your end goals. Understand how the API views the following entities.

- A **User** uses an application.
- A **Developer** develops Application.
- An **Application** has a [project id](https://console.developers.google.com/) and its associated [credentials](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849).
- A user authorizes an application to access their data via the API.

You are breaking this paradigm because you are the user and developer from the API's perspective. You want to share your data with people who are not authorized to view it, so you will need to use a service account to access that data and share it directly with your users.

Also remember to add the service account to [Analytics View](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618) you wish it to access.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) if you prefer not to get bogged down learning oAuth2, the CoreReporting API, and lastly a charting tool.  We simplify the process.  All you do is create your chart and embed a snippet of code in your site where you want the chart/dashboard to show.